# How to load resources with the same name from different locations in multiple ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to write an 'Application Server' which can deploy applications like Tomcat. When deploying an application, I create a customed ClassLoader instance and use it to load classes and resources within the application folder. There is a lot to learn about ClassLoader, and I'm still confusing with it.

My question is: Is there different 'class path' for different ClassLoader instance? Or are these ClassLoader instances looking for resources from the same location?

For example, 'app1' has a resource located at `apps/app1/classes/log4j.properties` and 'app2' also has one located at `apps/app2/classes/log4j.properties`, how to make app1's ClassLoader read it with the right path?

Answer (score 0):

That is for you to implement in your custom ClassLoader.

Supposing you start by extending `URLClassLoader`.

When you unpack/deploy your 'application' you must call `void addURL(URL url)` on your class Loader which *Appends the specified URL to the list of URLs to search for classes and resources.*

A process could be something like this

- get you application as a zip/war
- unpack in a directory
- get a list of your unpacked resources (jar, sub-directories, etc..) where you call a method on the class loader you instantiated for that application and that would look like this

_

```
public void addClassPaths( String[] classPaths ) throws IOException {

    for ( int i = 0; i < classPaths.length; i++ ) {

        String resource = classPaths [ i ];
        File file = new File( resource ).getCanonicalFile(  );

        if ( file.isDirectory(  ) ) {

            addURL( file.toURI(  ).toURL(  ) );
        } 
        else {

            URL url = new URL( "jar", "", "file:" + file.getCanonicalPath(  ) + "!/" );

            addURL( url );
        }
    }
}
```